# I can't find the zdpack command in Zend Framework or Server

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to create a Zend project following the instructions in the tutorial that the Zend Server provides.
It says to execute the command: zf create ProjectName. This is working perfectly for me.
The next step is to execute the command: zdpack create ProjectName, but Windows doesn't recognize the command zdpack. I'm working in a Windows environment.
I have searched any zdpack file but it is not in my Zend folder.

Does someone know where should the zdpack.bat be? 
Where could I download it?

Thanks a lot,
Victor

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Zend Server documentation](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/preparing_the_package_using_the_deployment_tool.htm):

```
Tool location - The tool is located in: Linux - '/usr/local/zend/bin/zdpack';
Windows - 'C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\bin\zdpack'
-OR- as a standalone (if downloaded separately from the product).
```

Could you find it there?

Comment: Any idea where the created files is at for ubuntu?